# Javascript event custom property disappears

Tags: javascript, events

I have an iFrame inside my document, which at one point triggers a custom event:

```
function notifyEnd(gameStatus) {
    var fireOnThis = parent.document;
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Event');
    evObj.gameStatus = gameStatus;
    evObj.initEvent('gameEnd', true, true);
    fireOnThis.dispatchEvent(evObj);
}
```

Please note the gameStatus property set on the event.

My document registers an event listener for this event:

```
document.addEventListener('gameEnd', function(e) {
    document.getElementById("gameEndForm:gameStatus").value = e.gameStatus;
    document.getElementById("gameEndForm:gameCompleteButton").click();
}, true);
```

However, when the event is fired, the "gameStatus" property has an "undefined" value. I couldn't find any clue as to what could cause such a behaviour.

Thanks for your help,
Sébastien

Comment: Events are, to some extent, internal data structures. I don't know that it's possible to rely on arbitrary attributes surviving the "dispatchEvent" wormhole trip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that you want to use a MessageEvent and use the data parameter of initMessageEvent.

http://help.dottoro.com/ljknkjqd.php

You can use JSON is you want to pass more than just one string.

Comment: I tried to use data parameter but I can't pass UTF-8 string by the parameter. How can I pass UTF-8 text by data parameter?